# I need specific data from a Dictionary inside a Dictionary from JSON

Tags: python, api

I wish to extract ONLY the catergory ID's from this JSON API response.

I currently have the following code where `dictstr` is the returned JSON

```
print(dictstr['Store']['CustomCategories']['CustomCategory'][0:-1])
```

This Prints out the following JSON:

```
{  
    'CategoryID':'20004239012',
    'Name':'Home Decor',
    'Order':'1',
    'ChildCategory':{  
        'CategoryID':'20215926012',
        'Name':'Furniture',
        'Order':'1'
    }
},
{  
    'CategoryID':'20004240012',
    'Name':'Christmas Decorations',
    'Order':'2'
},
```

The desired output I require is only the `CatergoryID` and `Name` key/values, like so:

```
['1', 'Other', '20004239012', 'Home Decor', '20215926012', 'Furniture', 
'20004240012', 'Christmas Decorations', '20270732012', 'Candle stands', 
'20270902012', 'Fireplace tools']
```

Comment: I think we might need a sample response or server code for this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.

Comment: i hope this makes sense! apologies for the timewaste.. im getting there..

Comment: something like `[e['CategoryID'] for e in d['CustomCategories']['CustomCategory']]` gets `['1', '11400059015', '11400060015 ', '11400061015']`

Comment: Thanks for updating the post, don't be too disheartened by the down votes - posting good questions is a skill you will pick up quickly

Comment: As long as there are people to keep things right... humanity will progress.

Comment: Did you get it working @johnashu? I posted a line of code in a comment above that should work. `[e['CategoryID'] for e in d['Store']['CustomCategories']['CustomCategory']]` gives me `['1', '11400059015', '11400060015 ', '11400061015']`

Comment: I am afraid i cannot comprehend it in a python sense.. My brain is out of fuel~! I really really really want to return what you returned!

Comment: i have updated the question

Comment: Can you post the full output of `api.response.dict()`

Comment: edited to add he full response reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you only need to go one level deep, you can do:

#### Code:

```
cids = [x for x in sum(
    [(d.get('CategoryID'), d.get('ChildCategory', {}).get('CategoryID'))
     for d in data], ()) if x]
```

#### How?

By iterating over the list, you can extract tuples of the fields (`d.get(...)`) and then use `sum()` to combine the tuples, and then finally drop any `None` (missing) elements.

#### Test Code:

```
data = [{
    'CategoryID': '20004239012',
    'Name': 'Home Decor',
    'Order': '1',
    'ChildCategory': {
        'CategoryID': '20215926012',
        'Name': 'Furniture',
        'Order': '1'
    }
},
{
    'CategoryID': '20004240012',
    'Name': 'Christmas Decorations',
    'Order': '2'
},
]

cids = [x for x in sum(
    [(d.get('CategoryID'), d.get('ChildCategory', {}).get('CategoryID'))
     for d in data], ()) if x]

print(cids)
```

### Results:

```
['20004239012', '20215926012', '20004240012']
```